# Nodejs, Socket.io redirect users to route

Tags: node.js, socket.io

what I need to achieve is that I can redirect user even if he is not in the lobby route, redirect it from lets say homepage to the match when its found. Right now everything works when everyone is in lobby route
point is that lets say I join the lobby, Im added in the database that Im in this lobby, and then let's say I go to market to get some stuff before that game, and while I;m in the market, match has been found and then I should be auto redirected to the match page

While I'm on the lobby page I get redirected to the match route.

This is my code:

Server side:

```
                io.emit('match-found', {
                    lobbyID: lobby._id,
                    enemyID: enemyLobby._id,
                    matchID: newMatch._id
                });
```

Client side:

```
socket.on('match-found', (data) => {
    if (data.lobbyID === lobbyID) {
        window.location.href = '/match/' + data.matchID;
    }
    if (data.enemyID === lobbyID) {
        window.location.href = '/match/' + data.matchID;
    }
});
```

Now I should probably do something like this in my serverside:

```
                UserLobby.find({lobby_id: lobby._id}).then((playersLobby) => {
                    // here I'm getting all the players that are in the lobby currently.
                });
```

Or do I need to emit new event which would somehow would redirect the specific users to the match route ?

Comment: What exactly is the question?  What doesn't work?  The two client-side redirects you show code for should work just fine (in that they will take the browser to the desired URL).

Comment: Everything works. Now I want to redirect the user that is in lobby even if he is not in the lobby route. Let's say he is added to the lobby and he went to the store to get some items and while he is in the store, I want to auto redirect him to match page when match is found @jfriend00

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  What does "in lobby" mean?  Does that mean they're in a "lobby" room in socket.io or they're on a particular page/route in the browser?  Or what?  If the server wants to tell a user's browser to change the page, you will have to do that via socket.io so your server will have to know which socket.io connection belongs to a user that you want to change the page on.  But, please realize it will be disconcerting to the user if they're interacting with a web page and all of a sudden, it goes to another page on its own.